# Acro package: Commas in the acronym

Tags: acronyms

I'm using the `acro` package, and I want to use a comma in one of the acronyms.  Unfortunately TeXnicCenter throws a wobbly:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/split-excess-tokens"
! 
! Too many ',' tokens when trying to split argument.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.24 ...m{pvt}{PVT}{process, voltage, temperature}

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| LaTeX was asked to split the input 'process, voltage, temperature' at each
| occurrence of the token ',', up to a maximum of 2 parts. There were too many
| ',' tokens.
|...............................................
```

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-long-format=\capitalisewords}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}% provides \capitalisewords

\DeclareAcronym{pvt}{PVT}{process, voltage, temperature}

\begin{document}
The environmental space is known as \ac{pvt} blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Clearly in its current form the only way I am going to get it to work is to remove the commas, however I'd very much like to have my cake and eat it.  So how do I get it written as:

> The environmental space is known as process, variation, temperature (PVT) blah blah blah...

Comment: Add another pair of braces: `\DeclareAcronym{pvt}{PVT}{{process, voltage, temperature}}`

Comment: or put braces around the commas

Comment: As well as what @cgnieder says, the input seems to be wrong as `\DeclareAcronym` only takes two arguments (according to the v1.0 documentation).

Comment: @cgnieder [OT] I notice none of your L3-dependent packages have been added to our prefix register: could I encourage you yo log them with me and I'll add them :-)

Comment: Well that seems to work, thanks @cgnieder.  Knew it wasn't a big ask but didn't expect it to be so simple.  I guess it helps when you know what you're doing ;)  
Do you want to write that up as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JosephWright I have that on my TODO list. Expect an email soon

Comment: @E_L I will but that'll have to wait a few hours until I'm home again

Comment: @E_L It seems that you're using a version 0.x of the package. Consider upgrading, as version 1.0 is surely more powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### version 1.*

The syntax for declaring acronyms is as follows:

```
\DeclareAcronym{<id>}{
  short = <short> ,
  long  = <long> ,
  <other key value pairs>
}
```

Here it is more or less obvious that a comma delimits the single key/value pairs and hence a value must be written in braces if it should contain one or more commas.

```
\DeclareAcronym{pvt}{
  short = PVT ,
  long = {process, voltage, temperature}
}
```

### version 0.*

With version 0.* the syntax of the command was different.

An acronym was declared by

```
\DeclareAcronym{<id>}{<short>}{<long>}
```

but this is only a little part of the truth. More accurate and the explanation for your issue is this:

```
\DeclareAcronym{<id>}{<short>,<plural ending>}{<long>,<plural ending>}
```

Both the `<short>` and the `<long>` argument are split by a possible comma where after the comma one can add a different plural ending than the default `s`. Your entry had two commas so `acro` saw the following:

```
\DeclareAcronym{pvt}{PVT}{process, voltage, temperature}
 - id:    pvt
 - short: PVT
 - long:  process
 - long plural ending: voltage (including a leading space)
```

and then it choked as it didn't expect a second comma. Workaround: hide the commas or the whole long entry in an extra pair of braces.

```
\DeclareAcronym{pvt}{PVT}{{process, voltage, temperature}}
```

Comment: I had the same trouble, but I simply enclosed in brackets the commas and it works \m/.  So, in the acronym declaration I use (in the traditional way) in the `long` field: `long = process{,} voltage{,} temperature, ` but I see the result is the same if I enclose all the field after the `=` symbol.

Comment: @Aradnix the difference is that the braces in your example will stay around the commas while a pair of braces around the whole value will be removed when the value is saved.